# java methods can be out of a class

Tags: java

I have this question on a homework assignment:

> The method `foo()` defined in the class `Quiz` has the following signature: `public static double foo(double f)`. What can you say about `foo()`?
>
> 1. It is a class method
> 2. It is an instance variable
> 3. It is an instance method
> 4. It is a class attribute

I am thinking it is a class method because `foo()` is declared in a class. Is the answer as straight-forward as I think?

Comment: It's a class method because of the `static` modifier.  That means it belongs to the `Quiz` class, and not to any particular instance of `Quiz`.

Comment: <rant>next time I'll go to SO to ask what time is it</rant>

Comment: @Qnan hey bro u mean to say not ask these kind of questions here?

Comment: @noobprogrammer nope, go on, it's fun and you help people earn some reputation

Comment: @Qnan ah tks when u rant tagged i got confused..hehe.

Comment: @noobprogrammer It is important you perform adequate research before deciding that posting on SO is the correct course of action. I think Qnan was assuming this research hasn't occurred, as the definitions of the answers (1-4) are available all over the Internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is that its a `class method`

a field or a method declared with `static` is always an **attribute or behavior of the class respectively.**

`Non-static` variables are **one per object**, where as `static variables` are **one per 
class**.

`static` method **do NOT** have **access** to the `Non-static` variables or methods.

`static` methods and variables can be called using the `Class_Name` with `"."` (dot) operator.

Though **if** the `class` **do NOT** have `private constructor` (**Math class has private constructor**), then you can also create an instance to class to call the static methods or variables, but thats **not the legal way to do it.**

You should also remember that, you can **call** `static methods or variables` using a **null Reference** of the `class` in which they reside.... Yes and it works....

Comment: then the last statement is also true if ur 2nd statement is true.. a bit contradicting..

Comment: `static method do NOT have access to the Non-static variables or methods.` is wrong. If you have a reference of this class (as parameter, in a static field, crated with `new`) it can access **all** methods and fields of that object, including `private` fields/methods.

Comment: @Johannes13 `If you have a reference of this class`, now please check that whether that reference  (ie object reference variable) of the class, is static or non-static, if its static, IT CANNOT ACCESS ANY NON-STATIC VARIABLES OR METHODS.... IF you still have any doubts, please refer Thinking in Java by Bruce Eckle or Head First Java by Kathy Sierra... or better try it our yourself...

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra a reference is **never** static. And so `public class MyObject {private boolean foo; public boolean doSomething(MyObject o) {return o.foo}}` works.

Comment: @Johannes13 sorry but reference can be static.... Have you tried making an Singleton class, where you declare and initialize the static object reference variable at the same time.... Eg:      `public class Test{ 
 public static Test uniqueInstance = new Test(); 
 
 private Test(){}

 public static Test getInstance(){

     return uniqueInstance;

 } 
 
}`

Comment: @Johannes13 i think either you or me are on different pages..... so i don't think its of any use to carry on this conversation or argument any further.... and yes..thanks for the discussion...

Answer (score 1):

Well, you`re half way there...

In java you have **Instace Methods** and **Class Methods**

Instance methods are methods that are tied to an Instance of a Class:

```
class InstanceTest {
    public void instanceMethod() { }
}
(...)
InstanceTest it = new InstanceTest();
it.instanceMethod();
```

For you to call this method, you will have to instace this class and the call it up.

A Class method - identified by the *static* modifier can be called directly on a class:

```
class ClassTest {
    public static void instanceMethod() { }
}
(...)
ClassTest.classMethod();
```

That 'rule' is the same for variable too, you can have instance and class variables.

You can learn more about Instance vs Class Members [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 0):

It's a class method but not because it's declared in a class but because it is `static`, hence it uses no instance variables of any object of the class they are defined in.

Answer (score 0):

It is a class method because of the use of the `static` keyword which means that you dont need an instance of the class to call it.

You call it like:

```
Quiz.foo(2.5);
```

In opposite, if it was an instance method (without `static` keyword) , you would need to instantiate before calling the method

```
Quiz q = new Quiz();
q.foo(2.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a class method because it is static method.It belongs to the class and not to object(instance).

A static method can access only static variables. The reason is obvious. Something that is common to a class cannot refer to things that are specific to an object.